# How to properly link native modules in an Electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron, ffi, ref

I am working on an Electron app where I pretend to use native modules. I need `ffi` and `ref` as dependencies in my project. I installed the libraries via npm and rebuilt the modules with `node-gyp rebuild` as suggested in documentation [Using Native Node Modules](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules). Everything compiled successfully, but when I try to require these libraries I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\build\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\build\Debug\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\build\Release\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\out\Debug\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\Debug\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\out\Release\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\Release\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\build\default\binding.node
 → C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\my_app\compiled\6.5.0\win32\ia32\binding.node
```

It is odd that the search paths do not correspond to library path, which should be pointing to `node_modules`. I can't figure out what is causing this problem.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rebuild native modules you'll have much better luck using [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) which will ensure that they're are being built against the version of electron you're using.

We're using `ffi` and `ref` with electron-rebuild and that was all that was required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, that is all that was needed. I have 64-bit node and, apparently, 32-bit electron, so i was compiling for target architecture x64 instead of ia32.